# javascript Dynamic HTML table row causing issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a `select option` on select of which I am creating an HTML table, As I am calling data from back-end on the basis of selected option so created table rows are dynamic

**what I am doing is**

- On change of select option, I am creating HTML table row, the rows are dynamic and are consist of input fields, `ItemName` is an auto complete so when I am selecting any item name and focusing out I am getting some corresponding value of that item and populating them in other Input fields
- After selecting ItemName I am shifting my focus on `pur. rate` then `UnitQty` after and then `Disc%` in between these there are some calculations going on and lastly when I press enter on `Disc%` I am creating new row and everything is same for new row the working process is same

**What is my issue**

- As doing above process suppose for drop-down selected option `Supplier 1` I was doing all that, but then I realize I have to do it for another supplier, i.e. here it is `Supplier 2`, So on selection of `Supplier 2` I am deleting `tbody` and `tfoot` and creating fresh one
- So after drop-down change new row is created and it should work the same as above, but what's happening is for 1st row it is taking right data, but when on `Disc%` I press enter to create new row it creates a new row, but `ItemName` is taking other supplier data like for `supplier 2` it is taking `supplier 1` data in second row

Please check my snippet I have put alert and comment for better understanding of the issue

````js
```
var CostPrice = "";
var totalAmount = "";
var unitQuantity = 0;
var unitQuantityOnDisc = 0;
var purchaseRateOnDisc = 0;
var purchaseRate = 0;
var totalAmount = "";
var discPercentage = "";
var discAmount = "";
var totalAmountOnDisc = "";
var subTotalOnDisc = 0;
var gstPercentage = "";
var gstAmount = "";
var totalAmountOnGst = "";
var total = 0;
var supplierCode = "";
var totalDiscountAmt = 0;
var totalGstAmt = 0;
var totalUnitQty = 0;
var subtotal = 0;
var totalAfterGrnDisc = 0;
var totalRoundOff = 0;
var totalAfterfreightAmt = 0;
var totalAftercommissionAmt = 0;
var mrpOnDisc = 0;
var tableData = {
  "ALMOND CHBAR~2402": {
    "itemName": "ALMOND CHBAR",
    "itemCode": "2402",
    "costPrice": 20.0,
    "gstPercentage": 14.5,
    "mrp": 30.0
  },
  "A BR SB EX~333": {
    "itemName": "A BR SB EX",
    "itemCode": "333",
    "costPrice": 1.0,
    "gstPercentage": 0.0,
    "mrp": 1.0
  }
}

var tableData1 = {
  "White rice~1001": {
    "itemName": "White rice",
    "itemCode": "1001",
    "costPrice": 50.0,
    "gstPercentage": 5,
    "mrp": 65.0
  },
  "Brown rice~333": {
    "itemName": "Brown rice",
    "itemCode": "1002",
    "costPrice": 90,
    "gstPercentage": 5.0,
    "mrp": 110
  }
}


$("#supplierInput").on("change", function(e) {
  $("tbody").empty();
  $("tfoot").empty();

  if (this.value == 'Supplier 1') {
    populateData(tableData)


  } else {
    populateData(tableData1)



  }

});

function populateData(data) {
  var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(data);

  function rowappend(tbody) {
    const markup =
      `<tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd"></td>
        <td>
          <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange" name="unitQtytd">
        </td>
                      
        <td>
          <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commanChange" name="discPercentagetd" >
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn"></i></td>
        
      </tr>`

    $(tbody).append(markup);
    setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);

    $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().autocomplete({
      source: autoCompleteData
    }).data('tableData', data); // <----   added...
  }

  function rowappendTfoot(tfoot) {

    const tfootmarkup =
      `<tr>
  <td id="itemNametf" class="commantf" align="center">Total ->
  </td>
  <td id="itemCodetf" class="commantf"></td>
  <td id="mrptf" class="commantd"></td>
  <td id="purRatetf" class="commantf"></td>
  <td id="unitQtytf" class="commantf"></td>
  <td id="discPercentagetf" class="commantf"></td>
  <td id="discAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
  <td id="gstPercentagetf" class="commantf"></td>
  <td id="gstAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
  <td id="totalAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
  <td id="crossBtntf" class="commantf"></td>
 </tr>`

    $(tfoot).append(tfootmarkup);

  }


  rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'))
  rowappendTfoot($('tfoot', '#tfootTable'))


  function getValues(row) {
    const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()
    console.log("search  : " + search);
    var data = $('[name=itemNametd]', row).data('tableData'); // <--- added
    const value = data[search]; // this one is causing issue
    CostPrice = value.costPrice;

    if (value) {
      $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").val(value.itemCode);
      $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val(value.mrp);
      $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val(CostPrice);

      $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val(value.gstPercentage);
    }
  }

  function calc(row) {
    unitQuantity = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val() || '0';
    purchaseRate = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val() || '0';
    var mrp = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").text() || '0';
    totalAmount = (parseFloat(unitQuantity) * parseFloat(purchaseRate));

    $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val((totalAmount));

  }

  function calcDiscount(row) {
    unitQuantityOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val() || '0';
    purchaseRateOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val() || '0';
    mrpOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val() || '0';
    subTotalOnDisc = (parseFloat(unitQuantityOnDisc) * parseFloat(purchaseRateOnDisc));
    discPercentage = $(row).find("[name=discPercentagetd]").val() || '0';
    gstPercentage = $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val() || '0';

    discAmount = (parseFloat(discPercentage) / 100) * parseFloat(totalAmount);
    totalAmountOnDisc = (parseFloat(totalAmount) - parseFloat(discAmount))
    gstAmount = (parseFloat(gstPercentage) / 100) * parseFloat(totalAmountOnDisc);
    totalAmountOnGst = (parseFloat(totalAmountOnDisc) + parseFloat(gstAmount))
    total += parseFloat(totalAmountOnGst);
    totalDiscountAmt += parseFloat(discAmount);
    totalGstAmt += parseFloat(gstAmount);
    totalUnitQty += parseFloat(unitQuantity);
    subtotal += parseFloat(subTotalOnDisc);
    totalRoundOff = total - Math.round(total);


    $(row).find("[name=discAmttd]").val((discAmount));
    $(row).find("[name=gstAmttd]").val((gstAmount));
    $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val((totalAmountOnGst));

    $("#unitQtytf").text((totalUnitQty));
    $("#discAmttf").text((totalDiscountAmt));
    $("#gstAmttf").text((totalGstAmt));
    $("#netAmtInput").val((total));
    $("#totalAmttf").text((total));
    $("#subTotalInput").val((subtotal));
    $("#itemAmtDiscinput").val((totalDiscountAmt));
    $("#taxAmtInput").val((totalGstAmt));
    //   $("#roundOffAmtInput").val(format(totalRoundOff));


  }

  $(document).on('focusout', function(e) {
    const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
    if (e.target.matches("[name=itemNametd]")) {
      getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
      $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();
    }
  });


  $(document).keypress(function(event) { // here I am trying to create new row when enter is clicked
    const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement
    if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {
      var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
      if (keycode == '13') {
        alert("presed")
        calcDiscount(event.target.parentElement.parentElement)
        if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
          rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)

          total = 0;
          totalDiscountAmt = 0;
          totalGstAmt = 0;
          totalUnitQty = 0;
          subtotal = 0;

          $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function() {
            calc(this)
            calcDiscount(this)
          })
        }
      }
    }





  });
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {

    const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
    if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]') || e.target.matches('[name=unitQtytd]')) {

      var keycode = e.keyCode || event.e;
      if (keycode == '9') {


        if (!$(event.target).val()) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }


        total = 0;
        totalDiscountAmt = 0;
        totalGstAmt = 0;
        totalUnitQty = 0;
        subtotal = 0;

        $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function() {
          calc(this)
          calcDiscount(this)
        })


      }

    }


  });
  $("#clear").click(function(e) {


    $("tbody").empty();
    $("tfoot").empty();
    $('#supplierInput option').prop('selected', function() {
      return this.defaultSelected;
    });
  });


}
````

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container commonDivInvoice">
  <div class="form-row">

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
      <label for="supplierInput">Supplier</label>
      <select name="supplierInput" id="supplierInput" class="form-control">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="true">select supplier
        </option>
        <option>Supplier 1</option>
        <option>Supplier 2</option>

      </select>
    </div>





  </div>
  <div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
          <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Code</th>
          <th id="mrpth" class="commanth">Mrp</th>
          <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
          <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
          <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
          <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
          <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
          <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
          <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>

    </table>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="tfootTable">
      <tfoot>


      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="commonButton" id="clear">
   <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i> Clear
  </button>
</div>
```

**Here is My dynamic Code for the people who are misinterpreting it**

To populate supplier `Select option`

```
$.ajax({
        'url': 'SupplierName', 
        'method' : "GET",
        'dataType' : "json",
        'contentType': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        'success': function(SupplierNamedata){
            let dropdown = $('#supplierInput');
            dropdown.empty();
            dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Supplier</option>');
            dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
          $.each(SupplierNamedata, function (key, entry) {
            dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.SupplierCode).text(entry.SupplierName));
        });

        },
        'error': function(err){ 

        } 
    });
```

So once supplier is populated I am selecting one from drop down and calling ajax like below

```
 $("#supplierInput").on("change", function(e) { 

                var supplierInvNo = $("#supplierInvNoInput").val();
                 $('#grnReceivingForm input[type="text"]').val('');
                 $('#grnReceivingForm input[type="tel"]').val('0.00');                              
                 $("tbody").empty();
                 $("tfoot").empty();

                supplierCode = this.value                   
                $.ajax({

                    url: "dataToPopulate",
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        supplierCode : supplierCode  // sending supplier code
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function(tabledata) { 

                            $("#tfootTable").show();
                            populateData(tabledata)
                          },
                   });
```

``
So by above code what I am doing dynamically is firstly populating the select option `drop-down` with supplier name, than on change of supplier I am calling data from backend for that supplier and that `tabledata` is updating each time when supplier is changed

Comment: Is it meant to be possible to have more than 1 supplier type in the table. E.g Can Row 1 be Supplier 2 and Row 2 be supplier 1?

Comment: @JonP no that is what I want to remove, when user changes supplier then i am deleting / empty previous supplier's row and want to create a new fresh one

Comment: @JonP row can only be based on one supplier selection, if supplier changes then `tbody` will be empty and user will create new rows for the supplier selected

Comment: Basically, you want whatever number of rows there is in table,  and you select that dropdown. all rows will be remove and should add new one. right??

Comment: Yup add new one and also the new row should take new data, you getting na?

Comment: yeah! right now its static using if else.

Comment: just not pupulating values as in json Object you have.

Comment: @RAVIPATEL static one I can't use because supplier names are dynamic so not possible to write if else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
The problem was, you placed **rowappend** function inside **populateData** function. This was causing always the first table object to be populated every time you add a row. 
Please check my updated text snippet and run it. You will see it work.

---

Please check my updated code snippet. Here, I am trying to **mimic** an AJAX call response by returning back an object. Compare my code with your original code to understand the changes:

```
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
            <label for="supplierInput">Supplier</label>
            <select name="supplierInput" id="supplierInput" class="form-control">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="true">select supplier
                </option>
                <option>Supplier 1</option>
                <option>Supplier 2</option>

            </select>
        </div>





    </div>
    <div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
                    <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Code</th>
                    <th id="mrpth" class="commanth">Mrp</th>
                    <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
                    <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
                    <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
                    <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
                    <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
                    <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
                    <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tfootTable">
            <tfoot>


            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="commonButton" id="clear">
        <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i> Clear
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    var CostPrice = "";
    var totalAmount = "";
    var unitQuantity = 0;
    var unitQuantityOnDisc = 0;
    var purchaseRateOnDisc = 0;
    var purchaseRate = 0;
    var totalAmount = "";
    var discPercentage = "";
    var discAmount = "";
    var totalAmountOnDisc = "";
    var subTotalOnDisc = 0;
    var gstPercentage = "";
    var gstAmount = "";
    var totalAmountOnGst = "";
    var total = 0;
    var supplierCode = "";
    var totalDiscountAmt = 0;
    var totalGstAmt = 0;
    var totalUnitQty = 0;
    var subtotal = 0;
    var totalAfterGrnDisc = 0;
    var totalRoundOff = 0;
    var totalAfterfreightAmt = 0;
    var totalAftercommissionAmt = 0;
    var mrpOnDisc = 0;
    var tableData = {};

    // ---- This block is to mimic jQuery API call response. I am using your own data ---- //

    sellersList = [
        {
            "SupplierCode": "0001",
            "SupplierName": "Amazon"
        },
        {
            "SupplierCode": "0002",
            "SupplierName": "FlipKart"
        },
        {
            "SupplierCode": "0003",
            "SupplierName": "eBay"
        }
    ];

    listOfItemsBySellerCode = {
        "0001" : {
            "ALMOND CHBAR" : {
                "itemName": "ALMOND CHBAR",
                "itemCode": "2402",
                "costPrice": 20.0,
                "gstPercentage": 14.5,
                "mrp": 30.0
            },
            "A BR SB EX~333" : {
                "itemName": "A BR SB EX~333",
                "itemCode": "333",
                "costPrice": 1.0,
                "gstPercentage": 0.0,
                "mrp": 20.0
            }
        },
        "0002" : {
            "iPhone SE": {
                "itemName": "iPhone SE",
                "itemCode": "2001",
                "costPrice": 15700.0,
                "gstPercentage": 14.5,
                "mrp": 20000.0
            },
            "Remi Note 5": {
                "itemName": "Remi Note 5",
                "itemCode": "2095",
                "costPrice": 25000.0,
                "gstPercentage": 13.0,
                "mrp": 28745.0
            }
        },
        "0003" : {
            "Levi's Jeans": {
                "itemName": "Levi's Jeans",
                "itemCode": "1309",
                "costPrice": 3750.0,
                "gstPercentage": 14.5,
                "mrp": 4120.0
            },
            "Fastrack M135": {
                "itemName": "Fastrack M135",
                "itemCode": "3401",
                "costPrice": 6789.0,
                "gstPercentage": 9.06,
                "mrp": 7459.0
            }
        }

    }

    function ajax_response_for_sellers_list (response) {
        return function (params) {
            params.success(sellersList);
        };
    }

    function ajax_response_for_items_sold_by_seller (response) {
        return function (params) {
            params.success(listOfItemsBySellerCode[params.data.supplierCode])
        }
    }

    // ****** Custom API response block ends here ******* //


    // Populate Supplier select options

    // Here I'm telling $.ajax to return with the seller data which I already have in my variable (for now). This way I don't even need to fire the API. 
    // But you can assume your API will respond in this JSON structure
    $.ajax = ajax_response_for_sellers_list();

    $.ajax({
        'url': '/mockAPI/to/get/suppliersData',
        'method': "GET",
        'dataType': "json",
        'contentType': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        'success': function (response) {
            console.log('Our Mock API responding with list of all sellers : ')
            console.log(response);

            let dropdown = $('#supplierInput');
            dropdown.empty();
            dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Select Supplier</option>');
            dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
            $.each(response, function (key, entry) {
                dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.SupplierCode).text(entry.SupplierName));
            });

        },
        'error': function (err) {

        }
    });

    // Here I'm telling $.ajax to return all items sold by a seller (seller is identified by code)
    // You can assume your API will respond in this JSON structure
    $.ajax = ajax_response_for_items_sold_by_seller();

    $("#supplierInput").on("change", function (e) {
        var supplierInvNo = $("#supplierInvNoInput").val();
        $('#grnReceivingForm input[type="text"]').val('');
        $('#grnReceivingForm input[type="tel"]').val('0.00');
        $("tbody").empty();
        $("tfoot").empty();

        supplierCode = jQuery(this).find(":selected").val();
        $('.loader').show();
        $('.overlay').show();
        $.ajax({

            url: "/mockAPI/to/get/items/based/on/sellercode",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                supplierCode: supplierCode  // sending supplier code
            },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {

                console.log('Our Mock API responding with all items sold by the selected seller : ', supplierCode)
                console.log(response);

                $("#tfootTable").show();
                populateData(response)
            },
        });
    });

    function rowappend(tbody) {
        const markup =
            `<tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange" name="unitQtytd">
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd"class="form-control commanChange" name="discPercentagetd" >
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td> 
                <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn"></i></td>

            </tr>`

        $(tbody).append(markup);
        setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);

        // Bind autocomplete data
        var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(tableData);
        $("[name=itemNametd]", $('tbody', '#tableInvoice')).last().autocomplete({
            source: autoCompleteData
        }).data('tableData', tableData); // <----   added...
    }

    function getValues(row) {
        const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()
        console.log("search  : " + search);
        var data = $('[name=itemNametd]', row).data('tableData'); // <--- added
        const value = data[search]; // this one is causing issue

        // Check first if the user is selecting an `existing` data object
        if (value) {
            CostPrice = value.costPrice;

            if (value) {
                $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").val(value.itemCode);
                $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val(value.mrp);
                $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val(CostPrice);

                $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val(value.gstPercentage);
            }
        }
    }

    function calc(row) {
        unitQuantity = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val() || '0';
        purchaseRate = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val() || '0';
        var mrp = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").text() || '0';
        totalAmount = (parseFloat(unitQuantity) * parseFloat(purchaseRate));

        $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val((totalAmount));

    }

    function calcDiscount(row) {
        unitQuantityOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val() || '0';
        purchaseRateOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val() || '0';
        mrpOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val() || '0';
        subTotalOnDisc = (parseFloat(unitQuantityOnDisc) * parseFloat(purchaseRateOnDisc));
        discPercentage = $(row).find("[name=discPercentagetd]").val() || '0';
        gstPercentage = $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val() || '0';

        discAmount = (parseFloat(discPercentage) / 100) * parseFloat(totalAmount);
        totalAmountOnDisc = (parseFloat(totalAmount) - parseFloat(discAmount))
        gstAmount = (parseFloat(gstPercentage) / 100) * parseFloat(totalAmountOnDisc);
        totalAmountOnGst = (parseFloat(totalAmountOnDisc) + parseFloat(gstAmount))
        total += parseFloat(totalAmountOnGst);
        totalDiscountAmt += parseFloat(discAmount);
        totalGstAmt += parseFloat(gstAmount);
        totalUnitQty += parseFloat(unitQuantity);
        subtotal += parseFloat(subTotalOnDisc);
        totalRoundOff = total - Math.round(total);


        $(row).find("[name=discAmttd]").val((discAmount));
        $(row).find("[name=gstAmttd]").val((gstAmount));
        $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val((totalAmountOnGst));

        $("#unitQtytf").text((totalUnitQty));
        $("#discAmttf").text((totalDiscountAmt));
        $("#gstAmttf").text((totalGstAmt));
        $("#netAmtInput").val((total));
        $("#totalAmttf").text((total));
        $("#subTotalInput").val((subtotal));
        $("#itemAmtDiscinput").val((totalDiscountAmt));
        $("#taxAmtInput").val((totalGstAmt));
        //    $("#roundOffAmtInput").val(format(totalRoundOff));


    }

    $(document).on('focusout', '[name=itemNametd]', function (e) {
        var row = jQuery(this).parent().parent();

        // Get row values
        getValues(row);

        // Focus next
        console.log('focusing next', row.find("[name=purRatetd]").length);
        row.find("[name=purRatetd]").focus();
    });


    $(document).keypress(function (event) { // here I am trying to create new row when enter is clicked
        const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement
        if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {
            var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
            if (keycode == '13') {
                alert("presed")
                calcDiscount(event.target.parentElement.parentElement)
                if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
                    rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)

                    total = 0;
                    totalDiscountAmt = 0;
                    totalGstAmt = 0;
                    totalUnitQty = 0;
                    subtotal = 0;

                    $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function () {
                        calc(this)
                        calcDiscount(this)
                    })
                }
            }
        }





    });
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {

        const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
        if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]') || e.target.matches('[name=unitQtytd]')) {

            var keycode = e.keyCode || event.e;
            if (keycode == '9') {


                if (!$(event.target).val()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return;
                }


                total = 0;
                totalDiscountAmt = 0;
                totalGstAmt = 0;
                totalUnitQty = 0;
                subtotal = 0;

                $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function () {
                    calc(this)
                    calcDiscount(this)
                })


            }

        }


    });
    $("#clear").click(function (e) {
        $("tbody").empty();
        $("tfoot").empty();
        $('#supplierInput option').prop('selected', function () {
            return this.defaultSelected;
        });
    });

    function rowappendTfoot(tfoot) {

        const tfootmarkup =
            `<tr>
            <td id="itemNametf" class="commantf" align="center">Total ->
            </td>
            <td id="itemCodetf" class="commantf"></td>
            <td id="mrptf" class="commantd"></td>
            <td id="purRatetf" class="commantf"></td>
            <td id="unitQtytf" class="commantf"></td>
            <td id="discPercentagetf" class="commantf"></td>
            <td id="discAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
            <td id="gstPercentagetf" class="commantf"></td>
            <td id="gstAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
            <td id="totalAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
            <td id="crossBtntf" class="commantf"></td>
        </tr>`

        $(tfoot).append(tfootmarkup);

    }

    function populateData(data) {
        tableData = Object.assign({}, data);
        var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(data);
        rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'));
        rowappendTfoot($('tfoot', '#tfootTable'))
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Nop same issue try this way 1:- select `supplier 1` create one row then again row 2,  2:- select `supplier 2` the above two rows created will be removed then create new row and when you again create new row for `supplier 2` no autocomplete is showing up instead of showing `supplier 2` data it shows up `supplier 1` data again

Comment: Got it. Let me check.

Comment: @manishthakur Please run my snippet again. It should work perfectly fine as per your requirement.

Comment: hey that approach is not fine, as I have edited my post as you can see there is only one data i.e `tableData` as you can check my ajax when user changes supplier I am calling data via ajax from backend as per selected supplier, here for better understanding I have defined tabledata1 and tableData, but I think you guys are mistaking it, suppose I have 30 supplier so what would I do should I make 30 if else, even that supplier nos are dynamic

Comment: In your snippet you have not added a working ajax call code. Please add a jsFiddle code that I can work with. I have already spent much time on this issue.

Comment: How can I add a working ajax I have added the ajax call but it will not show data because I am running it into my local system , please check my edit of my post the `tableData` in side success function is dynamic on change of dropdown

Comment: I think it is very common to understand that the drop-down field is not going to have only two options, on change of that I am calling tableData

Comment: Okay. Allow me sometime. I'll get back to you.

Comment: No issue at all you can take your time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195999/discussion-between-mohammed-furqan-rahamath-m-and-manish-thakur).

Comment: hey I told you that supplier is not static here for example I had took supplier 1 and supplier 2 but in my dynamic code I am loading it from data base it can be anything

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the data object globally used in all place.
which can be handle by fetching the object again based on selected dropdown in runtime.

Please check below code

```js
    var CostPrice = "";
    var totalAmount = "";
    var unitQuantity = 0;
    var unitQuantityOnDisc = 0;
    var purchaseRateOnDisc = 0;
    var purchaseRate = 0;
    var totalAmount = "";
    var discPercentage = "";
    var discAmount = "";
    var totalAmountOnDisc = "";
    var subTotalOnDisc = 0;
    var gstPercentage = "";
    var gstAmount = "";
    var totalAmountOnGst = "";
    var total = 0;
    var supplierCode = "";
    var totalDiscountAmt = 0;
    var totalGstAmt = 0;
    var totalUnitQty = 0;
    var subtotal = 0;
    var totalAfterGrnDisc = 0;
    var totalRoundOff = 0;
    var totalAfterfreightAmt = 0;
    var totalAftercommissionAmt = 0;
    var mrpOnDisc = 0;
    var tableData = {
      "ALMOND CHBAR~2402": {
        "itemName": "ALMOND CHBAR",
        "itemCode": "2402",
        "costPrice": 20.0,
        "gstPercentage": 14.5,
        "mrp": 30.0
      },
      "A BR SB EX~333": {
        "itemName": "A BR SB EX",
        "itemCode": "333",
        "costPrice": 1.0,
        "gstPercentage": 0.0,
        "mrp": 1.0
      }
    }

    var tableData1 = {
      "White rice~1001": {
        "itemName": "White rice",
        "itemCode": "1001",
        "costPrice": 50.0,
        "gstPercentage": 5,
        "mrp": 65.0
      },
      "Brown rice~333": {
        "itemName": "Brown rice",
        "itemCode": "1002",
        "costPrice": 90,
        "gstPercentage": 5.0,
        "mrp": 110
      }
    }

    var tableDataGlob = ''; //global object
    $("#supplierInput").on("change", function (e) {
      $("tbody").empty();
      $("tfoot").empty();
      if (this.value == 'Supplier 1') {
        tableDataGlob = tableData;
        populateData(tableDataGlob)
      } else {
        tableDataGlob = tableData1;
        populateData(tableDataGlob)
      }
    });


    function populateData(data) {

      function rowappend(tbody) {
        const markup =
          `<tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control commanChange" id="itemNametd" name="itemNametd">
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="itemCodetd" id="itemCodetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="mrptd" id="mrptd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="purRatetd" id="purRatetd" class="form-control commantd"></td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="tel" id="unitQtytd"class="form-control commanChange unitQtytd" name="unitQtytd">
                  </td>
                              
                  <td>
                    <input type="tel" id="discPercentagetd" class="form-control commanChange discPercentagetd" name="discPercentagetd" >
                  </td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="discAmttd" id="discAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td> 
                  <td><input type="text" name="gstPercentagetd" id="gstPercentagetd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="gstAmttd" id="gstAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="totalAmttd" id="totalAmttd" class="form-control commantd" readonly="readonly"></td>
                  <td style="background-color: white;border: 1px white"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x remove-btn"></i></td>
                  
                </tr>`

        $(tbody).append(markup);
        setTimeout(() => $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().focus(), 100);
        // Fetch Data on basis of dynamic Selected option 
        // Previously the code was declaring global var 2019-07-04 15:24:28
        var autoCompleteData = Object.keys(tableDataGlob);
      

        console.log(autoCompleteData);
        console.log($("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last());
        $("[name=itemNametd]", tbody).last().autocomplete({
          source: autoCompleteData
        }).data('tableData', data); // <----   added...

      }

      function rowappendTfoot(tfoot) {

        const tfootmarkup =
          `<tr>
        <td id="itemNametf" class="commantf" align="center">Total ->
        </td>
        <td id="itemCodetf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="mrptf" class="commantd"></td>
        <td id="purRatetf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="unitQtytf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="discPercentagetf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="discAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="gstPercentagetf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="gstAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="totalAmttf" class="commantf"></td>
        <td id="crossBtntf" class="commantf"></td>
      </tr>`

        $(tfoot).append(tfootmarkup);

      }


      rowappend($('tbody', '#tableInvoice'))
      rowappendTfoot($('tfoot', '#tfootTable'))


      function getValues(row) {
        const search = ($('[name=itemNametd]', row).val()).toString()
        console.log("search  : " + search);
        
        var data = tableDataGlob;
        console.log(tableDataGlob);
    
        const value = data[search]; // this one is causing issue
        CostPrice = value.costPrice;

        if (value) {
          $(row).find("[name=itemCodetd]").val(value.itemCode);
          $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val(value.mrp);
          $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val(CostPrice);

          $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val(value.gstPercentage);
        }
      }

      function calc(row) {
        console.log(row)
        unitQuantity = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val() || '0';
        purchaseRate = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val() || '0';
        var mrp = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").text() || '0';
        totalAmount = (parseFloat(unitQuantity) * parseFloat(purchaseRate));

        $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val((totalAmount));

      }

      function calcDiscount(row) {
        unitQuantityOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=unitQtytd]").val() || '0';
        purchaseRateOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=purRatetd]").val() || '0';
        mrpOnDisc = $(row).find("[name=mrptd]").val() || '0';
        subTotalOnDisc = (parseFloat(unitQuantityOnDisc) * parseFloat(purchaseRateOnDisc));
        discPercentage = $(row).find("[name=discPercentagetd]").val() || '0';
        gstPercentage = $(row).find("[name=gstPercentagetd]").val() || '0';

        discAmount = (parseFloat(discPercentage) / 100) * parseFloat(totalAmount);
        totalAmountOnDisc = (parseFloat(totalAmount) - parseFloat(discAmount))
        gstAmount = (parseFloat(gstPercentage) / 100) * parseFloat(totalAmountOnDisc);
        totalAmountOnGst = (parseFloat(totalAmountOnDisc) + parseFloat(gstAmount))
        total += parseFloat(totalAmountOnGst);
        totalDiscountAmt += parseFloat(discAmount);
        totalGstAmt += parseFloat(gstAmount);
        totalUnitQty += parseFloat(unitQuantity);
        subtotal += parseFloat(subTotalOnDisc);
        totalRoundOff = total - Math.round(total);


        $(row).find("[name=discAmttd]").val((discAmount));
        $(row).find("[name=gstAmttd]").val((gstAmount));
        $(row).find("[name=totalAmttd]").val((totalAmountOnGst));

        $("#unitQtytf").text((totalUnitQty));
        $("#discAmttf").text((totalDiscountAmt));
        $("#gstAmttf").text((totalGstAmt));
        $("#netAmtInput").val((total));
        $("#totalAmttf").text((total));
        $("#subTotalInput").val((subtotal));
        $("#itemAmtDiscinput").val((totalDiscountAmt));
        $("#taxAmtInput").val((totalGstAmt));
        //   $("#roundOffAmtInput").val(format(totalRoundOff));


      }

      $(document).on('focusout', function (e) {
        const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
        if (e.target.matches("[name=itemNametd]")) {
          console.log(e.target.parentElement.parentElement);
          getValues(e.target.parentElement.parentElement)
          $("[name=purRatetd]").focus();
        }
      });

      // $('.discPercentagetd').unbind();
      
      $('body').on('keypress','.discPercentagetd',function (event) { // here I am trying to create new row when enter is clicked
        const row = event.target.parentElement.parentElement
        if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]')) {
          var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
          console.log(keycode);
          if (keycode == '13') {
            alert("presed")
            calcDiscount(event.target.parentElement.parentElement)
            if ($(row).parent().find('tr').length - $(row).index() === 1) {
              rowappend(event.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement)

              total = 0;
              totalDiscountAmt = 0;
              totalGstAmt = 0;
              totalUnitQty = 0;
              subtotal = 0;

              $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function () {
                calc(this)
                calcDiscount(this)
              })
            }
          }
        }


      });


      $('body').on('keypress','.discPercentagetd,.unitQtytd', function (e) {

        const row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement
        if (event.target.matches('[name=discPercentagetd]') || e.target.matches('[name=unitQtytd]')) {

          var keycode = e.keyCode || event.e;
          if (keycode == '9') {


            if (!$(event.target).val()) {
              e.preventDefault();
              return;
            }


            total = 0;
            totalDiscountAmt = 0;
            totalGstAmt = 0;
            totalUnitQty = 0;
            subtotal = 0;

            $("#tableInvoice tbody tr").each(function () {
              calc(this)
              calcDiscount(this)
            })


          }

        }


      });

      $("#clear").unbind();
      $("#clear").click(function (e) {


        $("tbody").empty();
        $("tfoot").empty();
        $('#supplierInput option').prop('selected', function () {
          return this.defaultSelected;
        });
      });

    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <div class="container commonDivInvoice">
      <div class="form-row">

        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-2">
          <label for="supplierInput">Supplier</label>
          <select name="supplierInput" id="supplierInput" class="form-control">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="true">select supplier
            </option>
            <option>Supplier 1</option>
            <option>Supplier 2</option>

          </select>
          <input type="hidden" id="selectedtable" name="" value="">
        </div>





      </div>
      <div class="row tableInvoice" id="commonDvScroll">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInvoice">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th id="itemNameth" class="commanth">Item Name</th>
              <th id="itemCodeth" class="commanth">Code</th>
              <th id="mrpth" class="commanth">Mrp</th>
              <th id="purRateth" class="commanth">Pur.Rate</th>
              <th id="unitQtyth" class="commanth">Unit Qty</th>
              <th id="discPercentageth" class="commanth">Disc%</th>
              <th id="discAmtth" class="commanth">Disc Amt</th>
              <th id="gstPercentageth" class="commanth">Gst%</th>
              <th id="gstAmtth" class="commanth">Gst Amt</th>
              <th id="totalAmtth" class="commanth">Total Amount</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>

        </table>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="tfootTable">
          <tfoot>


          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="commonButton" id="clear">
          <i class="fa fa-eraser"></i> Clear
        </button>
    </div>
```

Test here working module:
https://jsfiddle.net/m4fb038x/

Comment: hey here `if ($('#selectedtable').val().trim() === 'Supplier 1') {      var data =tableData;    }` you are checking with if else because there are two suppliers only in select field, but in my real code they are 10-15 and many more and they are dynamic, and there is only one data object that is `tableData` which is dynamic when supplier changes I am calling that data from my backend which relates to the selected supplier, so for here I am using only two data i.e `tableData` and `tableData1` and `supplier 1` and `supplier 2` because of to display working snippet

Comment: $("#supplierInput").on("change", function (e) {
   $("tbody").empty();
   $("tfoot").empty();
   $('#selectedtable').val($("#supplierInput").val().trim());

   if ($(this).val().trim() === 'Supplier 1') {
    populateData(tableData);
   } else {
    populateData(tableData1);
   }

  });


//Make changes in on change event like this

Comment: hey first off all why to do this `var opt_table_Map = { 'Supplier 1' : tableData,'Supplier 2' : tableData1 }` I told you that data and suppliers are dynamic so no need to complicate things and when I am `selecting supplier 2` after selecting `supplier 1` the enter pressed two times why?

Comment: How you're gonna map the supplier with table data object. Let us know your dynamic code for same

Comment: I didn't get you why do i need to map then when I am selecting `Supplier 1` I am creating a table row, when I am selecting `Supplier 2` I am removing that row and creating new with new data via ajax

Comment: @manishthakur I got your problem. Check my latest code the problem can be handle by creating the global variable for tabledata which is fetch from ajax.

Comment: @Rishab The suggested answer is not needed. There was a mistake in @manishthakur 's code. He had added `rowappend` function in the wrong place which was always taking in the first table data object. If you take the `rowappend` function outside `populateData` function and pass the right table data object, it will solve the issue.

Comment: @manishthakur you just need to make the binding of Supplier dropdown and autocomplete data, while the rest piece of my code won't create the multiple click event on the press of entering on disc%.